# copy different sheet and make them one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheet 1 and 2. in sheet 1 I have a button that browse a file and paste it in into the second sheet so I need help to be able to browse for the second sheet and be able to paste it under the first one that is already exist in sheet 2. I would appreciate your help

```
Sub hh()
'
' hh Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:A11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B19").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2:A5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B30").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

i recoded this code manually

Comment: Are you trying to merge two sheets?

Comment: you completely deleted all of your code and pasted new code that is unrelated to the original code / description about copying and pasting data. (that still exists above the code block)
IF you have a second question you should close this one and post a second one. NOT edit the question after it's answered and post a second completely new question.

Comment: After I answer this one are you going to edit the question a third time with a new problem? And no, your first question was a chunk of code that used copy and paste which I fixed below. This new code is asking "why does this separate chunk of code unrelated to the original question open a sheet in a new Excel".

Comment: yep it does,so can you plz help me.i need it to open on same excell

Comment: I've rolled this back to your original question. Rather than editing this so extremely that you make the answers no longer relevant, I'd suggest asking a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer was for the original question with `Sub hh` which has since been edited out to create a new question*

First of all your original code can be rewritten as:

```
Sub hh()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A11").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Paste
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A5").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B30").Paste

End Sub
```

Now you can modify the paste location based on the 'last row' which is what I believe you are asking. The last row would be found like this:

(comments in line)

```
Sub hh()

'Varible to store the last row in
Dim iLastRowSheet1 As Long

'copy initial data to memory
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A11").Copy

'find current last row
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRowSheet1 = .Range(B & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'paste using last row found + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & (iLastRowSheet1 + 1)).Paste

'repeat
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A5").Copy
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRowSheet1 = .Range(B & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & (iLastRowSheet1 + 1)).Paste

End Sub
```