# How to paste a excel file from external

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem of pasting a values into my excel,i have 2 sheet 1 and 2.in sheet 1 its where i put my Button,textfield
I have a broswer which fetch a excel file and I want to paste that excel file into sheet 2.

At the moment i am able to broswe and select file , but I cant paste the information into sheet 2, Can anyone help me.

```
Dim fileStr As String
Sub GetOpenFile()

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Value = fileStr

End Sub
Sub Button3_Click()

Workbooks.Open fileStr

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong terminology. Are you trying to copy the worksheet from one excel workbook to another?

Comment: yes i want to copy from 1 workbook to another

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim fileStr As String, wbk1 as workbook, wbk2 as workbook

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()

set wbk1=activeworkbook
set wbk2=Workbooks.Open (fileStr)

wbk2.sheets(1).cells.copy wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(1,1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Please remember to accept the solution if your question is fully answered.

Comment: @nutsch good luck on getting your ✔. I answered a question for Op on a different thread today about a subroutine called `hh` and instead of awarding points he deleted/edited the question and posted a new one.

Comment: @Gimp did you notify the mods?

Comment: @nutsch yeah an awesome mod came and fixed it, after I reported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807545/copy-different-sheet-and-make-them-one-sheet Gave you a +1 for answering the question I refused to after the previous post morphed. :]